# How does Panchang predict agricultural conditions?

Tags: astrology, panchang, mathematics

There are research papers which mention that panchangs are more accurate than IMD in terms of climate prediction. Moreover, I read that there are multiple predictions possible, over and above rainfall prediction.
Can I know if there is any document/book which discusses how this is calculated?
I would like to know how it is calculated, and not the links where predictions are available.

Comment: In any Panjika, we find such information for the farmers-like when to sow the seeds and etc.  But I don't know how these are calculated.. It is not mentioned in the Panjika itself.

Comment: Sharing one of the researches regarding the panchang being more accurate : https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229449364_Meteorological_predictions_preserved_in_the_Panchangam_versus_real-time_observations_-_a_case_study_over_Tirupati_region_-_a_semi-arid_tropical_site_in_India?enrichId=rgreq-b3c52ff57bbae368cbad0f9d636da526-XXX&enrichSource=Y292ZXJQYWdlOzIyOTQ0OTM2NDtBUzoxMDEwODQ1ODQ0ODA3NjlAMTQwMTExMTg1MTE3Mw%3D%3D&el=1_x_3&_esc=publicationCoverPdf

Comment: There are more such resources, so hoping to understand how the agriculture/climate related predictions are done. Any views?

Answer (score 1):

It comes under mundane Astrology. Sometimes a horoscope is delineated considering location such as Sumeru or Vindhyā at other times, specific verses from Brihat Samhitā, etc. are interpreted. You can look at [this research paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/229450465_Meticulous_and_meritorious_meteorology_enshrined_in_the_Brihat_Samhita_-_A_comparative_case_study_over_four_Indian_regions_situated_in_diverse_climatic_zones) to know how it is carried out in the later case.